¿Como remapear una tabla y un objeto @dataclass en python?
Comunidad buen dia!
Me dirijo a ustedes con el máximo respeto, sobre una incertidumbre en como "re- mapear objetos con tablas en sqlalchemy en python", estoy utilizando el enfoque DDD (Domain-Driven Design), por lo que mi modelo esta implementado en un bloque de codigo separado de la implementacion de la tabla, esto para poder realizar el código de forma ordenada y limpia, y poder implementar el patrón de diseño "repository".
Esta investigación la he llevado realizando 1 semana, he encontrado como "re-mapear" pero en objetos que no son @dataclass, mis fuentes son las siguintes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209471/sqlalchemy-re-map-class
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.clear_mappers
Mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo una @dataclass y una tabla, como lo vemos en el siguiente codigo:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import NewType
from sqlalchemy.ext.instrumentation import InstrumentationManager
from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,String,Table,MetaData,Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry
from DB.config_connection import papercompany_url #Unicamente devuelve una URL para realizar la conexion
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#Este es el objeto que representa a la tabla en la base de datos.
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ProductNew:
    IDPRODUCTS:int
    PRODUCTNAME:str
    PRODUCTPRICE:float

#Esta es la tabla, que deseo correlacionar con el objeto
metadata=MetaData()
product_table=Table(
    "products",
    metadata,
    Column('IDPRODUCTS',Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True),
    Column('PRODUCTNAME',String(255)),
    Column('PRODUCTPRICE',Float)
)

despues comeienzo realizando el mapeo de los 2 objetos
#Mapeo de los 2 objetos
products_mapper=mapper_registry.map_imperatively(ProductNew,product_table)
#Creando el engine
engine=create_engine(papercompany_url)
#Definiendo la sesion
Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)
#Instanceando la sesision
session=Session()
#Imprimiento en pantalla los elementos que contiene la tabla.
print(list(session.query(ProductNew).all()))

El problema que tengo es ha la hora de "des-mapear los objetos"
El codigo utilizado para esto es el siguiente:
metadata.remove(product_table)
mapper_registry.dispose()

metadata.remove(product_table)
mapper_registry.dispose()

esta porcion de codigo me lanza el siguiente error:
  File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Flask_projects\Flask_login_excersice7\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_api.py", line 1451, in dispose
    mapperlib._dispose_registries({self}, cascade=cascade)
  File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Flask_projects\Flask_login_excersice7\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 4283, in _dispose_registries
    reg._dispose_manager_and_mapper(manager)
  File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Flask_projects\Flask_login_excersice7\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_api.py", line 1461, in _dispose_manager_and_mapper
    instrumentation._instrumentation_factory.unregister(class_)
  File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Flask_projects\Flask_login_excersice7\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\instrumentation.py", line 168, in unregister
    super().unregister(class_)
  File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Flask_projects\Flask_login_excersice7\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\instrumentation.py", line 645, in unregister
    manager.unregister()
  File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Flask_projects\Flask_login_excersice7\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\instrumentation.py", line 313, in unregister
    self._adapted.unregister(self.class_, self)
  File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Flask_projects\Flask_login_excersice7\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\instrumentation.py", line 251, in unregister
    delattr(class_, "_default_class_manager")
AttributeError: _default_class_manager

Tengo que decir que tambien he intentado con clear_mappers, pero el resultado es el mismo, el error que me arroja es "_default_class_manager"
